# Why isn't my C matrix performing the way I expect?

Tags: c, gcc, matrix

I'm attempting a project in C and I'm pretty confused by the results I'm getting.  I've done quite a bit of research on how the arrays are handled and I feel like it should work. Below is my code:

```
for( i = 0; i<1000;i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j<1000; j++)
            {   
                if(j==0)
                    matrix[i][j] =i;
                else{
                    double value = (i-j)/j;
                    printf("%s%d\n","value of i-j: ",value);
                    matrix[i][j] = value;
                    printf("%s%d\n","value stores in matrix: ",*matrix[i][j]);
                }


        }
    }
```

matrix is a double array declared outside of any functions like so:

```
double matrix[1000][1000];
```

When I run the program, I get a separate value for the printout of 'value' and a different value for the printout of matrix[i][j] and I do not understand why they are different.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put the asterisk in front of matrix in printf, as that interprets the data as an address and "dereferences" it.
Also, if you want to print a double, you need to use %f instead of %d.
And if you want to calculate `(i-j)/j` as a double (instead of integer division) you need to use a cast on one of the operands of the division operator.

```
for( i = 0; i < 1000;i++)
{
    matrix[i][0] = i;
    for( j = 1; j < 1000; j++)
    {   
        double value = (i-j)/(double)j;
        printf("value of i-j: %f\n", value);
        matrix[i][j] = value;
        printf("value stored in matrix: %f\n", matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing the result of matrix[i][j] which is wrong since the array notation by default dereferences the index. Remove the * before the matrix access. Also change your format specifier to %lf.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s%d\n","value stores in matrix: ",*matrix[i][j]);
```

why do you deference the matrix??

change it to

```
printf("value stored in matrix: %lf ", matrix[i][j]);
```

you cannot specify the string literal like that in C. if you still want to print a string try

char *s = "value stores in matrix:"

then

```
printf("%s%lf\n",s,matrix[i][j]);
```